# javascript arrays forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to learn javascript. The instructor makes a To-do list in which he uses forEach to create index no. and write the todo in the next line. Somewhat like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grqru.png)

Here's the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2gWa.png)

My question is : How does forEach work? We haven't even defined the "todo" and "i" (=index). How can it it capture the index on it's own and also, shift a new task on a new line? 
Please try to explain forEach in a simpler(non-technical) language.
Thanks!!

Comment: please add the relevant code in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the documentation about foreach here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Essentialy, foreach is a builtin function of the array type taht will call an other function it receives on every item of an array.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain in a "non-technical" language how this works. But you need at least to know what arrays, functions and parameters are, in the most basic way...

forEach is a function that works on an array, it's a builtin function of the Array object in Javascript, meaning you can call it doing `myArray.forEach` if `myArray`is a Javascript Array.

It takes a function as parameter, it is called a *callback function*. That callback function will be called ***for each*** object in the array. It takes as parameters the *value* and the *index* of the object: `myArray.forEach(function(value, index){});`.
Here, `function(value, index){}` is your callback function. You have to write the code you want to execute on each object inside the brackets.
For example, the following code:

```
["First object", "Second object"].forEach(function (value, index) {
   console.log("//Index = " + index.toString() + " and value = " + value);
});
```

will give you the following output in the console:

```
//Index = 0 and value = First object
//Index = 1 and value = Second object
```

For more *technical* details about forEach, try the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach